# Почему перевод строки это CR+LF а не LF+CR?

Tags: linux, windows, macos, ascii

Ведь по идее сначала происходит подача новой строки, а уже потом возврат каретки https://youtu.be/oxN1C2QQUIE

PS Пользователям macOS и linux: у вас реально только один символ LF?

Comment: Да, реально один

Comment: Один. Тут скорее вопрос с Microsoft. Это их решение по поводу двух символов.

Comment: У mac'ов как раз один CR, если не поменяли. Под Unix - один LF. Форточки - CR+LF

Comment: @Мелкий поменяли, CR был только в Mac OS 9, а уже с OS X стал LF, как во всех юниксах

Comment: Но разницы то нет в каком порядке выполнить эти операции. результат от порядка не зависит. И в зависимости от того на сколько тугой рычаг и того на сколько легко движется каретка, эти действия происходят одновременно. И кстати, если вам по какой то причине надо только поменять строку, но не двигать при этом каретку, вы воспользуетесь ручками прокрутки сбоку, а не рычагом, потому что вероятность, что каретка успеет немного продвинуться пока будете использовать ручку очень высока

Comment: А еще у нас нету шрифта Ариал и Таймс Нью Роман. Как жить теперь? Ты сможешь жить с этим знанием?

Comment: Блин нет печатной машинки под рукой.

Comment: @bukkojot Ну Times New Roman вроде есть.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Википедия [объясняет](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#History) это так: при печати на [телетайпе](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BF) возврат каретки длился больше, чем печатается один символ. Поэтому если сначала перевести строку, а потом вернуть каретку и печатать дальше, то первый символ печатался где-нибудь в середине строки.

Порядок CR, LF был выбран, чтобы дать каретке небольшую фору. Даже её могло быть недостаточно, и тогда после отправлялась некоторая пустая последовательность.

> только один символ LF

Начал использоваться в ОС Multics, где перевод каретки принтера (и, по всей видимости, ожидание до конца перевода) осуществлялся его драйвером. CR без новой строки можно было использовать для **разных** <s>декоративных</s> эффектов. Из Multics LF перешел в Unix, а оттуда в остальные ОС.

Comment: @sanmai спасибо!